# is not a valid collection option, mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to create a collection in MongoDB, but I get an error:

> 'name' field is not a valid collection option

I am using MongoDB version 4.0.0. The code:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/newApp', (err, db) =>{
    if (err) {
        return console.log('mongodb connection error'); 
    }

     db.createCollection('people', {
        name: 'sarah',
        age: 27,
        location: 'honolului',
        relationship: 'unknown'
    }, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                return console.log('query has not successed retry error code ' + err);
            }

            conole.log(result.ops);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Collection in mongodb don't have defined properties. The second parameter of createCollection is options. You can check it here. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createCollection/

Answer (score 0):

You are using it with a wrong way, you have to use it like:

**For More help:**

> https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createCollection/

```
db.createCollection( "people", {
       validator: { $jsonSchema: {
          bsonType: "object",
          required: [ "phone" ],
          properties: {
             name: {
                bsonType: "string",
                description: "must be a string and is required"
             },
             age: {
                bsonType : "number",
                description: "must be a number and match the regular expression pattern"
             },
             location: {
                 bsonType: "string",
                description: "must be a string"
             },
             relationship: {
                bsonType: "string",
                description: "can only be one of the enum values"
             }
          }
       } }
    } )
```

***Note:*** Validator will give you the options to apply your custom validation method like `required` or `unique`.